# Windows 7 PC becomes very slow on heavy copy

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, performance

My PC configuration: Intel Core 2 Duo 2.4 MHz, 3 GB RAM, Hitachi 160 GB + Samsung 320 GB HDD, Asus P5B-VM Motherboard. I was using Windows XP Profession on Hitachi HDD for 2 years. Found no problem when copying gigabytes of data in Hitachi hard disk from one place to another. I've recently started using Windows 7 Ultimate in newly bought Samsung HDD (model: HD322HJ). Now my PC becomes almost unusable when heavy copying occured. Any idea why this could happen? Both of my HDD's are SATA 3.0, 3 Gb/s speed. The new Samsung HDD is 7200 RPM which is greater than Hitachi's.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so there are two variables here.. the OS and the hard drives. Did you have Windows 7 with the old 2 drive setup and it was fine?

Comment: @jeff, no i didn't try that. i recently bought a new 750 GB hdd and found it slightly faster than the 320 GB hdd, though they have same RPM and same 32 MB buffer.

Comment: @Donotalo higher capacity drives generally have higher transfer speeds due to the higher storage density on the disk platter itself.  The computer should not be unresponsive when transferring files, but remember that HDDs can only do *one thing at a time*, so **you should** experience slow-downs trying to multitask with any hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defrag both drives, star using alternative copy manager (ex. Total Commander, TeraCopy).

Scan both drives with HD Tune (check overall health), check transfers.